# How to get all the forms from a DLL Delphi Application

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I want to get all the forms from a Delphi DLL Application for Casting, something like this but not using MDIChild forms but fsNormal forms: (This is from Delphi 4, I need something similar in Delphi RAD STUDIO but I dont know how to accomplish this)

```
for i:= Application.MainForm.MDIChildCount-1 downto 0 do
    if (Application.MainForm.MDIChildren[i] is FormNameNeeded) then
    begin
      variable := (Application.MainForm.MDIChildren[i] as FormNameNeeded).FunctionNeeded;
      break;
    end;
```

Comment: Do you mix Delphi 4 and Delphi 2010 to build main EXE and DLL?

Comment: @PeterWolf, nope I just want something similar but at the moment all I have is this DELPHI4 example of the main idea of my requirement.

Comment: It is not really clear what you actually want. DLLs don't keep track of the Forms they have, so there is no direct way to iterate them.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The scope is to refresh (close/open) one ClientDataset component from Form1 using Form2, Form2 is ManualDocked to a Form1 PageControl. I Thought it could be accomplished by casting going through all the forms like the example I'm showing, so I can get access to the ClientDataSet components of Form1 from Form2

Comment: Please don't distract readers with irrelevant code "something like this, but totally different" Instead show the code how you populate the `MainForm.PageControl` with the form(s) it hosts and what information you want to access from the main form (or the embedded form).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have said in your comment to clarify (*completely restate*) your problem, you don't need to iterate over all forms.

You are in the context of Form2.  As `Form2` is "ManualDocked to a Form1 PageControl" then the `Parent` property of Form2 will be the PageControl (or more likely the TabSheet)

Given the TabSheet it's trival to get to the Form that is hosting it.  You could use something like this:

```pascal
  var
    pCandidate:  TComponent;
  begin
    pCandidate:=Self.Parent;
    if(pCandidate<>nil) then
    begin
      while((pCandidate<>nil) And not(pCandidate is TForm1)) do
        pCandidate:=pCandidate.Owner;
    end;
    if(pCandidate<>nil) then
      TForm1(pCandidate).FunctionNameNeeded();
  end;
```